# Check if device is exchanging data in network - Android

Tags: android, networking

Android can tell if device is uploading, downloading or exchanging (both upload and download). E.g.: At the bottom of Wi-Fi/Data notification icon, you'll see two arrows, up means upload and down means download, if up or down arrow is lighting, Internet is being used.

There's an example (up arrow is lighting, so something is being uploaded):
[image: Data exchange]

How to check if Internet is being used (uploading, downloading or both)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) to listen for data activity and its direction. As per documentation, onDataActivity (int direction) is used by status bar to display appropriate data icon.

You can find an example of its usage [Here](http://www.truiton.com/2014/08/android-phonestatelistener-example/)